# How to change the pixel value from Nan to zero and One?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an one image array of shape `(4, 64, 256)`.
At pixel `[63, 0]` I found nan values.

```
output[:, 63, 0] -----> array([nan, nan, nan,  1.])
```

So after using `output = np.nan_to_num(output)`, succesfully I got:

```
output[:, 63, 0] -----> array([0., 0., 0., 1.])
```

Then I am unable to get like this:

```
output[:, 63, 0] -----> array([0., 0., 1., 1.])
```

I tried `new = output[np.where(output[2, 63, 0] == 0), [2, 63, 0]] = 1`

but it gives 1 as output instead of `array([0., 0., 1., 1.])`

please help me solve this.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to achieve?

Just changing the entry `output[:,63,0]` from `array([0., 0., 0., 1.])` to `array([0., 0., 1., 1.]`?

Comment: from [4,64,256] image array, we have at [63,0] point an array ----> [0,0,0,1] so I want to to get at same point an array like:[0,0,1,1], It means when I access my output [:,63,0]. It should give [0,0,1,1]

Comment: In that case use 1. from the [answer of JohnTanner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54421533/10960882)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to accomplish:

1. if you just want to set a single "0" to "1", just use: `output[2,63,0] = 1`
2. if you want all "0" be "1" use: `output = np.where(output == 0, 1, output)` (see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
3. if you want just the "0" in one channel be "1", use: `output[2,:,:] = np.where(output[2,:,:] == 0, 1, output[2,:,:])`

Hope this helps!